# Clear browser cache with query string approach

Tags: javascript, browser-cache, offline-caching

I need to clear browser cache when I push an updated javascript file on server. A simple answer would be to use below technique of query string.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myjsfile.js?{my file version}"></script>
```

It would work but

1. Do I need to do this on every single `script` tag of every single
   page of my application?
2. Can I do this at main screen like login which loads at the beginning
   and I assume that would clear the cached file with new one, would it
   work?

Comment: seems like you should be using a master page and injecting html into it for each subpage. that way your script refs and style refs are localized to one page, easy to update everything at once. (if you use your querystrings properly too, you can avoid having poor breadcrumbing and bad SEO)

Answer (score 1):

*"Do I need to do this on every single script tag of every single page of my application?"*

Yes you do. The cache is based on the file's url, including those extra parameters.
Adding those parameters doesn't actually remove the file from the browser's cache, it more or less sees it as a new, different file.

This also answers point 2, since having to do it on all pages means you can't do it on only one page.