# Disabling caching in a built SPA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching

How it works: I build the app, and put it online using FTP. The problem is, the browsers cache the old version of my React app.

To use the new version I have to manually clear cache. Obviously, users will not know how to do it.

How can I disable the caching of my code?

I am using [linuxpl.com](https://www.linuxpl.com) hosting. I literately have no idea what I should include, if you need some info please let me know and I'll provide it.

Comment: Adding a query string to your app assets may help (e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393503/clear-browser-cache-with-query-string-approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force a browser "clear" its cache you can generate unique file names every time you create a build.

If you use `webpack` for to create a production build - you can read more how to deal with it [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/).

Comment: I'm just using `yarn build` does it make sense to change it to webpack?

Comment: @AlexIronside `yarn build` just executes some task (defined in `package.json`). What the task exactly do - depends on your configuration. Have you created your `SPA` using some boilerplate project like `create-react-app`?

Comment: Yes. I was using `create-react-app`

Comment: @AlexIronside So then you already should have `webpack` configured properly to generate different file names for your assets each time you run `yarn build`.

Comment: I just tried building it 2 times and the name was `main.38f79161.js` both times

Comment: @AlexIronside have you changed anything in **js** code in between of these tries? `38f79161` will not change if you haven't change any component or so.

Comment: Ok this changes the name. So that's weird, because I still need to manually clear cache every time

Answer (score 1):

Your server can tell the browser not to cache items. In NGINX (or whatever you server is running), you'll want to add a header along the lines of

```
add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
```

so that the browser knows to always fetch fresh versions.

Comment: Where should I include this? Something like .htaccess?

Comment: @AlexIronside yes in your nginx config